# My Rectangle Collision(With Images) Detection fires before touching?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I'm trying to figure out why my collision detection for these two images seem to fire before they touch. I've tried multiple simple detection algorithms but I keep running into the same issue.

EDIT - forgot the link http://exclusivebarbershopnj.net/canvas/Row.html

Here's the Rectangle function

```
function Rectangle(x, y, width, height) {
    var I = I || {};

    I.x = x;
    I.y = y;
    I.width = width;
    I.height = height;

    I.intersectsWith = function(rect) {
        return (rect.x < this.x + this.width && this.x < rect.x + rect.width && rect.y < this.y + this.height)
    }

    return I;
}
```

And here's the code that sees if they hit.

```
function boathit() {
    var rect = new Rectangle(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    lilypads.forEach(function(lilypad) {
        var rect2 = new Rectangle(lilypad.x, lilypad.y, lilypad.width, lilypad.height);

        if(rect2.intersectsWith(rect)) {
          console.log('rect');
          console.log(rect);
          console.log('rect2');
          console.log(rect2);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm really stumped here, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The little boat and the lilypad aren't rectangles, they're convex polygons. What happens when you use squares and disable rotation on the little boat?

Comment: http://exclusivebarbershopnj.net/canvas2/Row.html

I added a dot instead in the above link, it still detects it outside the box.

Comment: You're drawing the little dot at the mouse position instead of at the player position, then you use the player position to do collision detection. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Ah, my bad I forgot to update it. I see it's much closer now than before. Is there just really no accurate to get the collision detection with images?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very readable like this, and it seems like you're missing a check.

Try using this instead (I'm assuming that if x is the left bound, than x+width-1 is the right bound and so on):

```
I.intersectsWith = function(rect) {
  var rects = [
    { left: this.x, right: this.x+this.width-1, top: this.y, bottom: this.y+this.height-1 },
    { left: rect.x, right: rect.x+rect.width-1, top: rect.y, bottom: rect.y+rect.height-1 }
  ];

  return rects[0].left <= rects[1].right && rects[1].left <= rects[0].right &&
    rects[0].top <= rects[1].bottom && rects[1].top <= rects[0].bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit. I added that in but it didn't seem to work well, am I missing something else?

Comment: Not sure... try using some console output (replace the `return rects[0].left...` with `var res = rects[0].left....; console.log(rects, res); return res;`). See if that tells you anything interesting

Comment: Will do. I will update you on how it goes, thanks Amit!